# What does "foreign currency" mean in this context?

Tags: credit-card, foreign-currency

I'm looking to sign up for the [Chase Freedom Unlimited credit card](https://creditcards.chase.com/cash-back-credit-cards/freedom/unlimited?CELL=6TKX) as I'm about to make a >$500 purchase and would like to receive the $200 bonus offer. This purchase would be made on a foreign website and in a foreign currency.

However, in their Offer Details I see:

> ("Purchases" do not include balance transfers, cash advances, travelers checks, ***foreign currency***, money orders, wire transfers or similar cash-like transactions, lottery tickets, casino gaming chips, race track wagers or similar betting transactions, any checks that access your account, interest, unauthorized or fraudulent charges, and fees of any kind, including an annual fee, if applicable.)

Is this referring using the credit card to *withdraw* foreign currency, or is this referring to any purchases *involving* foreign currency?

Thanks! Any help/clarification is much appreciated!

Comment: In short, it means as you say *withdrawing* foreign currency.  If you buy some jeans, in Japan, that's fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the context, it's referring to buying money and things that are equivalent to money (e.g. travelers checks).  These are what they call "cash-like transactions".

Buying something from an overseas web site that operates in a currency other than your own isn't buying money.

Buying foreign bank notes, for a holiday overseas, is a "cash-like transaction".